# Какие есть опасные управляющие символы юникода?

Tags: xss, уязвимости, php, utf-8, unicode

Какие опасные символа юникода вы знаете и как их экранируете?

Вот пример того как можно применить один из таких символов

http://f-bit.ru/344646

после скачивания файла смотрим на его расширение и запускаем.

> там вся фишка в том что расширение
> файла показывается другим чем на самом
> деле
>
> я посмотрел его можно залить на любой
> файло обменник
>
> не пробовал, но что если подделать
> расширение на php - можно ли будет
> получить доступ к серверу?
>
> и никто практически не знает про эту
> фишку

Comment: @fdjgfjfgdj, Вы бы толком объяснили, что там по Вашейй ссылке. 

Я вижу какое-то имя файла. Ну и что?

Comment: @avp: имя файла на самом деле `КОД__` `<хитрый символ Unicode>` `gpj.bat`. Этот самый хитрый символ заставляет остаток строки показываться задом наперёд.

Comment: @VladD, да... Интересная штука. Из той же серии, что неразрывный пробел. 

Прочел в ответе @fori1ton, такие символы называют управляющими.

Comment: ага, я еще в заголовке написал про управляющие символы когда вопрос писал ;)

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не получится. Управляющие символы Юникода влияют на **отображение** имени файла, само же имя ОС распознаёт корректно и получить доступ к файлу по **отображаемому** имени у вас не получится, только по реальному. Кстати, Windows уже в диалоге сохранения показывает настоящее имя файла. В винде подержка Юникодовских имён файлов есть только в NTFS, FAT успешно юникодовские символы игнорирует.

**UPD**

Проверил под Linux в Firefox. Та же картина. Видимо, стандартные API операционных систем, в отличие от браузеров, не заморачиваются с корректным отображением управляющих символов Юникода.